# Closing an app with a keyboard shortcut(Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

How to close application by keyboard shortcut?

I tried this:

```
QAction *Ctrl_Q_Enter = new QAction();
Ctrl_Q_Enter->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Control + Qt::Key_Q + Qt::Key_Return);
QObject::connect(Ctrl_Q_Enter, SIGNAL(triggered()), app, SLOT(quit()));
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You have to add the action to something for it to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Action as you created it, is living alone in a vacuum and has no way of receiving key press or shortcut events. Add the action to menu `QMenu::addAction()` or to some widget (e.g. main window) using `QWidget::addAction()`. Only then the events will be routed to this action. Btw. the action should have a parent to avoid memory leak.

Btw. if you do not use a menu, then you probably to not need to use `QAction`. Creating `QShortcut` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qshortcut.html#QShortcut-1 and setting your main window as its parent should be sufficient. `QShortcut` is more a lightweight object then `QAction`. Unlike `QAction`, `QShortcut` does not contain name, tooltip, icon and other heavy stuff.